# Why UDF call is being executed before the WHERE clause in a CTE?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, user-defined-functions, common-table-expression

I'm trying to understand why a CTE (Common table expression) with a UDF (User defined function) call is so slow.

- Table TABLE1 has 10 million rows.
- The last where clause (ROWN = 1) is filtering and returning only 10 records.

For a unknow reason, MYFUNCTION is called million of times (before the WHERE clause filter) and it is slowing down the query. If MYFUNCTION call is removed, the query runs instantly.

How can I force SQL to run MYFUNCTION only after the WHERE clause is applied?

---

```
WITH MAINDATA
AS
(
    SELECT
        FIELD1,
        FIELD2,
        FIELD3,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY FIELD5 ORDER BY FIELD6) AS ROWN
    FROM
        TABLE1
)
SELECT
    FIELD1,
    dbo.MYFUNCTION(FIELD2, FIELD3) AS FUNCTIONRESULT
FROM
    MAINDATA
WHERE
    ROWN = 1
```

Comment: Probably because costing of scalar UDFs is garbage (until the work done on froid is released) - can you re-write it as an inline TVF?

Comment: @MartinSmith I can't, it's a complex function. Converted to CLR UDF and it's impressively faster. Just want understand the reason why SQL decided to call the function before filtering.

Comment: Can you add the UDF definition if possible? It might help understand if Froid will be able to inline the UDF.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try adding a sequential cte?

```
WITH MAINDATA
AS
(
    SELECT
        FIELD1,
        FIELD2,
        FIELD3,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY FIELD5 ORDER BY FIELD6) AS ROWN
    FROM
        TABLE1
) ,
RESULTS (
        SELECT 
            FIELD1
        FROM
            MAINDATA
        WHERE
            ROWN = 1
)
SELECT *
      ,dbo.MYFUNCTION(FIELD2, FIELD3) AS FUNCTIONRESULT
FROM  RESULTS
```